# Show div with class name equal to json array value using jquery and php when clicking on li with the same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a directory of folders within an img folder each titled with a folder name that I would like to equate to sections of the page I'm working on. The idea is that someone could drop whichever folders with images they want into the site directory and those images would be added to the html automatically in divs based on the folders they're in.

I've set it up so that php gets all the folder names and adds them to a list as list items with classes based on the folder name. I've set it up so that php also adds the images in those folders into div's based on which folder the image is in. I've hidden all those divs and I want the user to be able to click on the list item with the same class as the section they're trying to view. I feel like I'm almost all the way there but I'm getting an error in console that I can't seem to figure out. 
the error is `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.img/more` which I can't understand since that is the correct classname.
div.img/more changes correctly in console to the folder/class names based on the li I click.

I've tried googling my problem but it seems too complicated to really get a good search result.
If there is an easier way to do this I would love to hear it! It would be easy if I knew exactly which folders would be in the directory but I won't have that information.

```css
img {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.img-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 

   <?php 

      $imgPath = "img";
      $dirPaths = glob($imgPath . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    ?>


 <!doctype html>
 <html>
    <body>
          
        <?php 
          foreach ($dirPaths as $path) {
              $images = glob($path . "/*");?>
            
              <div class='img-section <?php echo $path; ?>'>

                <?php 
                  foreach($images as $image) {?>
                    <img src='<?php echo $image ?>'>
                <?php } ?>
               </div>
         <?php } ?>
          
       <ul></ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
           

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('paths.php', function(jsondata) {
       $.each(jsondata, function(index, value) {
         var valueTrunc = value.split("/").pop();
         $('ul').append("<li class='" + value + " " + index + "'>" + valueTrunc+ "</li>");
          
       });
        
      $('li').on('click', function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
            var $jsondata = jsondata[i];
            if ($(this).hasClass( jsondata[i] )) {
              $('div.' + $jsondata).show();
            }
          }
        });
     }); 
   });
        </script>

            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Insert your ajax inside a function that will trigger the click event.

Comment: I had thought about doing it that way but couldn't wrap my head around how I would get it to work without knowing the names of the folders/classes. It looks like my problem is actually that jquery or javascript doesn't like the class with / in it. I'll have to try to change that and see if it fixes my problem and if it doesn't I'll have to try to figure out a way of doing it like your suggestion.

Comment: aha! I used .split() to get rid of img/ for everything and it works now!